# Linux command to list file systems available for mounting?

Tags: linux, terminal, filesystems

What terminal command will return data that includes the file systems that are currently available for mounting on my system?

Specifically, I am using Ubuntu 15.04, though I would prefer an answer that is valid for all *nix users.

NOTES: 
I don't want to know what *IS* mounted, I want to know what is available.
I don't want to check the type of file system (ext2, ext4, ntsf, etc.), I want to know which file systems are available to be mounted (sda2, fd1, etc.).

Comment: Do you mean which *filesystems* (e.g, ext4, xfs, tmpfs) are available, or what *disk devices which potentially contain filesystems* (e.g, sdb1, sdd3) are available?

Comment: @duskwuff No, I do not mean file system TYPES (ext4, etc.), I mean file systems (which are formatted to a type). Please see CompTIA for clarification of the terms.

Comment: What you are describing sounds like storage devices, not file systems. If CompTIA uses the phrase "file systems" to describe this, I'm sorry, but they are wrong.

Comment: This is likely a question of semantics, I will clarify.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On Ubuntu you can use to show discs:

```
sudo lshw -class disk
```

or to check all partitions on your system

```
sudo blkid -o list | grep "not mounted"
```

or if you just want the device:

```
sudo blkid -o list | grep "not mounted" | awk '{print $1}'
```

Comment: Just to point out, since you edited, the command `sudo blkid -o list | grep "not mounted"` is the one that was correct.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding the question *"command will return data that includes the file systems that are currently available for mounting on my system".*

Granted from the powerful PROC file system, the available (or, static + dynamically installed) file systems in a running Linux could be found by:

```
cat /proc/filesystems
```

In my linux 3.10.0, the result is:

```
$cat /proc/filesystems  

nodev   sysfs  
nodev   rootfs  
nodev   ramfs  
nodev   bdev  
nodev   proc  
nodev   cgroup  
nodev   cpuset  
nodev   tmpfs  
nodev   devtmpfs  
nodev   debugfs  
nodev   securityfs  
nodev   sockfs  
nodev   dax  
nodev   bpf  
nodev   pipefs  
nodev   configfs  
nodev   devpts  
nodev   hugetlbfs  
nodev   autofs  
nodev   pstore  
....
```

This is the meta-data, the "mount" command will find and use.

Then, with below command, it lists all the mounted file systems.

```
$cat /proc/mounts

/dev/sda1 /boot xfs rw,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota 0 0
...
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/devices cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices 0 0
```

The third field of each line, like xfs or cgroup,  is the "file system", which is just mentioned in previous command.

Comment: I don't see "ntfs" on list form `/proc/filesystems` but I can mount it (although only in read-only, but still)?

Comment: Check souce code /fs/ntfs/super.c, is anything different?  
 ': .name  = "ntfs",'   || 'MODULE_ALIAS_FS("ntfs");'  || 'register_filesystem(&ntfs_fs_type);'

Comment: Yep, alias is set to `ntfs` in source of debian buster kernel ([4.19.181-1](https://sources.debian.org/src/linux/4.19.181-1/fs/ntfs/super.c/)). But I now see ntfs-3g was installed, that why I could mount it. I assume it has been stripped from the debian kernel too, just like .e.g. openSUSE (perhaps even upstream?)

Answer (score 0):

You can list all the predefined filesystem in your /etc/fstab

The fstab file contain all the filesystem that are usually mounted on boot or can be ready for mount (Like the CDROM drive).

If you want to the current mounted filesystem you have just to type the command:

```
mount
```

or

```
cat /proc/mounts
```

and if you want to know which devices can you mount, you have take a look to kernel messages (specially when hotplug device like USB memories are used) using the following command:

```
dmesg
```

Comment: Just to point out, I explicitly said that I do not want the current mounted filesystems.